# Create Pivot Table from data in .csv using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, pivot-table, powercli

I have a .csv file, I want to take all the data from one column and produce a pivot table with it using powershell. This column has many duplicates in and I want to see how many of each item there are. Attached are images of what i would like to be done through powershell instead of manually in excel. First image is example data, and the second image is what I want to be produced from the data. Thanks for any help :)

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwpUC.png)   [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhDbh.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doug Finke made a wonderful PowerShell module called `Import-Excel` which you can [get here.](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

If you're on PowerShell v5 or higher, you can install it like so:

```
Install-Module ImportExcel -scope CurrentUser
```

This module features some awesome Pivot functions, here's an example:

```
Get-Service |
    Export-Excel "c:\temp\test2.xlsx" `
        -Show `
        -IncludePivotTable `
        -IncludePivotChart `
        -PivotRows status `
        -PivotData @{status='count'}
```

[image]

I don't have access to your source data, but you could run something like this:

```
Import-CSV C:\yourPath\YourFile.csv | Export-Excel "c:\temp\OSReport.xlsx" `
    -Show `
    -IncludePivotTable `
    -IncludePivotChart `
    -PivotRows 'Operating System' `
    -PivotData @{'Operating System'='count'}
```

I just mocked up a file with some OS counts and ran it through that code.  Here's the result.

[image: If you have this many Windows 98 machines...seek new employment or give me a call to come help you fix it!]

I hope this gets you headed in the right direction!

**An important note about this tool:**, you must provide a new file name every time you run `Export-Excel` or it throws an ugly error message.  Either script the deletion of the file, or change the file name every time to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see those images, but it should be something like

```
$list = Import-Csv -Path P:\ath\to\file.csv -Delimiter ";"
$duplicates = ($list | Group-Object -Property <ColumName>).Where({ $_.Count -gt 1 })
```

Replace the  with the name of the Column you want to search for duplicates.

The 2 main functions you need are [Import-Csv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) & [Group-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object)

Consider, that Import-Csv creates PSCustomObjects in an array and the first rows in your colums are their properties.

So if you have a csv file like:

```
Column1;Column2;Column3
foo;bar;baz
baz;bar:foo
```

You'll have an Array of PSCustomObjects withs Column1,Column2,Column3 as properties. If your csv-file has no Column Name in the first line, you can use Import-Csv with the argument -Header ColumName.

All in all, what you want to do is a simple job, just read about the functions I linked and you'll do it :)

Greetz Eldo.O